# How making a biblabel dependent from a cite command?

Tags: biblatex

The question is very simple. I am using biblatex and biber. I want three things:

1. If I use a new command `\citer` which produces the number of the cited text between bra-kets (ex. see, for references <1>.), then in the bibliography, this text has its number enclosed in bra-kets (ex. <1>. E. Schröder, Ueber die iterirte Funktionen,...)
2. If I use a command `\cite*` which produces the number of the cited text without brackets (ex. see, for references 1.), then in the bibliography, this text has its number without any sort of parentheses (ex. 1. E. Schröder, Ueber die iterirte Funktionen, ...)
3. If I use a command `\citet` which produces the number of the cited text enclosed in square brackets (ex. see, for reference [1].), then in the bibliography, this text has its number enclosed in square brackets (ex. [1]. E. Schröder, Ueber die iterirte Funktionen,etc).

Is it possible?

Comment: And what should happen if you use in one chapter \citer{schroeder} and in the next \citet{schroeder}? Do you then want a number <[1]>? One can certainly make the labels dependant from some bool or category set by a cite command, but the whole idea sounds not really senseful.

Comment: This is certainly possible if you can explain what you want to do with works cited with multiple different `\cite...` commands. Also note that `\citet` is `natbib`-speak for `\textcite`, so you may want to use another name to avoid confusion. BTW: what would `\cite` do?

Comment: For example, typing "see, for further references \cite{schroder1}". I would obtain in the main text: "see, for further references <1>", and in the bibliography "<1>. E. Schröder, Ueber iterirte Funktionen, etc". I noted that whatever command I use in the text, in the bibiliography I have ever the numbers of the item enclosed in square brackets.

Comment: You seem to restate your question (well, `\cite` didn't play a role before, but OK), but do not answer our questions. How would a bibliography look like for a work cited with both `\cite` and `\citet`? Also could you explain on what `biblatex` style we are building here (I assume `numeric`)? An [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) could be very helpful especially if you can use it to show a mock-up of what you want.

Comment: I just noted you have asked [a similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/271765/35864) before (it wasn't about `biblatex` back then), but didn't respond to my questions either. I still have no idea what you want to do with corner cases and such.

Comment: I have a Job which requires such constraints. The items inserted by the Editors must have the number of their Label enclosed in bra-kets.

Comment: I'm not particularly interested why you want this, but what you want. What do you do if you cite the same item with `\citet` and then `\citer`?

Comment: I want obtain with \citet, the number of the biliographic item, without parentheses at all, and in the bibliography at the end, the same Thing: number without parentheses. With the command \citer, on the contrary, I want the number of the bibli. items enclosed in $\langle$ and $\rangle$, and I want that this number appear so also in the bibliography at the end of the book.

Comment: I repeat my question: What ought to happen to an item cited with both `\citet` *and* `\citer` in the bibliography? Implementing all this seems quite possible, but not knowing what to do in corner cases such as this I will not attempt a solution.

Comment: Is my English so bad? Using bitex, in the preamble I inserted this: \makeatletter
\renewcommand\@cite[2]{%
 Ref.~#1\ifthenelse{\boolean{@tempswa}}
 {, \nolinebreak[3] #2}{}
}
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother

Comment: and in the bibliography: \newcommand{\mybibitem}[1]{\stepcounter{enumiv} \bibitem[{$\langle$}{\arabic{enumiv}}{$\rangle$}]{#1}}

Comment: This way, using in the text \citen{label} and in the bibliography, \mybibitem{label} I obtained in both cases the Label enclosed in bra-kets. Then, the question: is this possibile in biblatex and biber? If yes, in what way? Ist das mit biblatex und biber möglich? Wenn ja, wie? É possibile con biblatex e biber. Se sì, in che modo? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know what ought to happen if you cite one work with multiple commands, but you can take the following solution

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{bra}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{brackets}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{none}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\mkbibbra}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \ensuremath{\langle}#1\ensuremath{\rangle}%
  \endgroup}
\newrobustcmd{\mkbibbraspace}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \ensuremath{\langle}#1\makebox[0pt][l]{\ensuremath{\rangle}}%
  \endgroup}
\newrobustcmd{\mkbibbracketsspace}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \blx@bibopenbracket#1\makebox[0pt][l]{\blx@bibclosebracket}%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citer}[\mkbibbra]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \addtocategory{bra}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \addtocategory{none}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citet}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \addtocategory{brackets}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{%
  \ifcategory{bra}
    {\mkbibbraspace{#1}}
    {\ifcategory{brackets}
       {\mkbibbracketsspace{#1}}
       {\ifcategory{none}
          {#1}
          {#1}}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\citer{sigfridsson} \cite*{worman} \citet{geer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. Perfect. To add a Point after the number of the bibentry, is it sufficient insert \addperiod in \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}? Many thanks and excuse me for the mess.

Comment: Another question, using my files the bibliography items are not starting from the same Point. The items with parentheses are starting more towards left. Please, let me know how can I post the file.tex and the file.bib.

Comment: @davidebond That is probably because the brackets take up different spaces. Try the massively more convoluted update above.